# Loop list while adding to it

Tags: c#, loops, backgroundworker

I've built my system in c-sharp (winforms) and I've run into a problem. In my view - my graphical interface - I'm starting a pretty heavy algorithm, which in each loop adds a result to a list in my view. The algorithm runs in a presenter (MVP pattern), using a backgroundworker - enabling the view not to freeze. As I said before, the algorithm runs in a loop, and since it's so heavy, I want to process the results of the algorithm as they come in.

View:

```
...
public List<string> Results { get; }
...
_presenter.RunAlgorithmAsync();
//Start processing results
...
```

Backgroundworker in presenter:

```
...
_view.Results.Add(result);
...
```

To sum it up, how can I start processing the list while the backgroundworker adds to it? Of course, the backgroundworker can work faster than the processing of the list, and vice versa - the processing may have to wait for results to arrive to the list, and the list need to be able up build up a stack of results.

I realize this question may be blurry, but if you ask me questions, I'm sure I can define the problem better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a queue and have the two threads treat it as a [producer and consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).

Answer (score 2):

Make the BackgroundWorker call a method in the view which adds the item to the list and processes it.

Comment: Or better yet - calls a delegate supplied by the controller that does that. Just a bit more decoupling of the background-worker from the GUI.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you would have to process the item before proceeding with the algorithm?

Comment: @Ben: No; that should be an asynchronous (non-blocking) call.  (using `BeginInvoke`)  `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` already does.

Comment: Okay, the info may have been insufficient. The processing is actually being made by a user. Therefore, I don't want the backgroundworker to call a method in the view. It should be better if the view is rather waiting for results.

Answer (score 2):

Use a threadsafe queue to drive your producer/consumer pattern, such as the .NET 4 ConcurrentQueue:  http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/02/04/NET-40-and-System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentQueue.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is it something that you can use the `ObservableCollection` and catch the `CollectionChanged` event to catch and process each item as it's added to the collection?